# Inertiajs add open graph meta tag

Tags: vuejs3, facebook-opengraph, inertiajs

what I have tried it using the head tag by inertia.

```html
<Head>
    <!-- HTML Meta Tags -->
    <title>{{ product.name }}</title>
    <meta name="description" :content="product.summary"/>

    <!-- Open Graph Meta Tags -->
    <meta property="og:url" :content="http://localhost/${product.slug}/${product.id}/`"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
    <meta property="og:title" :content="product.name"/>
    <meta property="og:description" :content="product.summary"/>

    <!-- Thumbnail Meta Tags -->
    <meta head-key="og:image" property="og:image"
          :content="`http://localhost/${product.thumbnail.path}-size-300.${product.thumbnail.mime}`"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300"/>

    <!-- Locale Meta Tags -->
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_MY"/>
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="zh_CN"/>
</Head>
```

However, this code doesn't detected by the Facebook, since it is dynamic generated after javascript have run

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to use SSR or prerendering with [vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) plugin to make the meta tag available for bots

Comment: I'm wondering how to achieve this also, I wanted to try vue-meta, but it seems like with Vue 3 there are some issues, so I tried [vue-social-sharing](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing), but it seems like it doesn't support image which is extremely important. I wish there was a simple way to implement meta like this with Inertia. Have you found a solutioin?

Answer (score 0):

**March 2024:** I didn't want to enable or SWITCH to SSR, so in my case, using PHP for the Backend ( Laravel ), I decided to use the **session vars.**

**Dynamic Tags Without SSR for server-side routes:**

```
 <!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta name="description" content="{{ session('meta_description', 'Default Description') }}">
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ session('meta_title', 'Default Title') }}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ session('meta_description', 'Default Description') }}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ session('meta_image', 'Default Image URL') }}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ session('meta_url', 'Default URL') }}">
<!-- Add more OG tags as needed -->
@routes
@vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
@inertiaHead
```

Inertia has no way to enable SSR for a single page only, like Next.js does.

https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering

Answer (score -1):

InertiaJS now offers the  component. This can be useful for SEO-related stuff. https://inertiajs.com/title-and-meta